# Navigation drawer item click updating child fragment again and again

Tags: android

In navigation drawer i have a child fragment with a list view. By clicking the drawer item first time, the list view is displayed but when closing and reopening the drawer by clicking on the same drawer item, the list view in child fragment is updated i.e. new list item is added in the list view of child fragment with the previous values of list view ..please help..i am stuck

```
int select=0;
select=position-2;
        String sendto =list.get(position-2).getIMEI();
        String sendtoname=list.get(position-2).getName();
        System.out.println(deviceIMEI+"--"+sendto+sendtoname);
    Fragment fragment = new ChatFrag();
    Bundle args1 = new Bundle();
    args1.putString(ChatFrag.MYIEMI, deviceIMEI);
    args1.putString(ChatFrag.SENDERIEMI, sendto);
    args1.putString(ChatFrag.SENDERNAME,sendtoname);
    args1.putInt(ChatFrag.SELECT, select);
    fragment.setArguments(args1);
    fm.beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment)
    .commit();
```

this is the code..please help how to remember the index..

Answer (score 0):

Reason is that the `Drawer` `ListView` `onItemClick` will be called when ever an item in the List is clicked. This is the behavior of `ListView`.

One way to fix this is to keep remembering the `last selected index` and avoid adding the `Fragment` again on next time `if the selected index is same as last selected`.

Another way is to check the `FragmentManager` if the `Fragment` is already added

```
    List<Fragment> fragmentList = getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments();

    if(fragmentList != null) {
        for (Fragment fragment : fragmentList) {
            if (fragment != null && fragment instanceof CustomFragment) {
                // don't add the fragment again
            }else{
            // add the fragment here
        }
    }
```